# Determine actual and displayed size of picture object in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA, I'm trying to determine both the actual and the displayed size of a picture object on a worksheet. The displayed size can be different from the actual size due to scaling factors. So far, I've found the methods `ScaleWidth` and `ScaleHeight`, but I don't want to actually modify the picture object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, it seems that the original measurements are not a public property of a picture. If you do not want to modify the original picture, you can create a duplicate of the said picture just for the scaling purpose.

This function accepts a shape (a picture in our case) and returns an array of Single type (width and height)

```
Private Function GetOriginalMeasurements(ByRef myShape As Excel.Shape)
    Dim shpCopy As Excel.Shape
    Dim measurements(1) As Single

    Set shpCopy = myShape.Duplicate

    ' Reset original measurements
    shpCopy.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue

    measurements(0) = shpCopy.width
    measurements(1) = shpCopy.height

    shpCopy.Delete

    GetOriginalMeasurements = measurements
End Function
```

The Main() procedure is just a basic example of how to use it

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myShape As Excel.Shape
    Dim measurements() As Single
    Dim width As Single
    Dim height As Single

    Set myShape = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    measurements = GetOriginalMeasurements(myShape)

    width = measurements(0)
    height = measurements(1)

    Debug.Print width
    Debug.Print height
End Sub
```

On my computer the duplicating and deleting of the shape is instant, but if you see some flickering, you may wish to turn off screen updating in that function.

Comment: A note of caution: there are three sizes to be taken into account. 1) the size on screen 2) the size as inserted in the program 3) the resolution on disk. If an image has e.g. a dpi of 150, PowerPoint scales the image to its screen dpi of e.g. 72, so that you see the image as about half the original size. If you extract the image (or choose save as...) and then check the dimensions of the file, you will notice it's much larger than expected.

Comment: You can also check the sizes by renaming a PowerPoint file to .zip and then opening the zip file. There is a ppt/media folder that contains all original images. This can also explain how sometimes the size of a PowerPoint file on disk is larger than expected.